# Change view in all collection view cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift4, swift5

I have a collection view where each cell has a video (played through AVPlayer) and a red circle. When a button in the view controller is clicked, the color of all cell's circles should be changed to blue, and then if clicked again, changes it back to red.

So what I need to be able to do is: when the button is clicked in the controller view, change the circle view in all cells, visible or not. The reason I say visible or not is because I only show one cell on the screen at a time. The user swipes to go to the next cell.

I have already tried using `reloadData()` to update all cell's circles when the button is clicked, however, the problem I discovered is that the video resets back to the beginning (and I need it not to do that, not just for the visible cell, but for all cells).

What are my other options?

Comment: Your main problem is reusability even if you call reloadData(), it will only load the visible cells, so you need to save in your cells or the data of the cells some sort or variable which tells the cell what state you are currently in. also i suggest not updating the cell through awakeFromNib but a custom initialisation func

Answer (score 0):

When a button in the view controller is tapped you would need to change the data/collection/array of data that you are loading in your collection view. In order to achieve the result in (for example `didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`) you should change the data model for that specific cell/collection item. You can add for instance property `isSelected` for your collection view data model(s).

In your case, calling reload data calls all the `UICollectionViewDelegate & UICollectionViewDataSource`methods, however since you have not change the data using, the result/UI returns to the initial state.